# how to tell find command to only remove contents of a directory

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am using `find` to get both files and dirs inside `$dest_dir` and remove them:

```sh
dest_dir="$HOME/pics"
# dest_dir content:
#  dir1
#  dir2
#  pic1
#  pic2

find $dest_dir -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

- **Expectation**: remove `dest_dir` contents only (i. e. dir1, dir2, pic1, pic2) and not dest_dir itself
- **Actual result**: the command removes the `dest_dir` too

I also tried `-delete` instead of the `-exec rm -rf {} \;` section, but it can't remove non-empty directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```sh
find "$dest_dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Option `-mindepth 1` will find all entries inside `"$dest_dir"` at least one level down and will skip `"$dest_dir"` itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a directory name to `rm -rf` it will delete it, by definition. If you don't want to recurse into subdirectories, why are you using `find` at all?

```sh
rm "$dest_dir"/*
```

On the other hand, if you want to `rm -rf` everything *inside* the directory ... Do that instead.

```sh
rm -rf "$dest_dir"/*
```

On the third hand, if you do want to remove files, but not directories, from an arbitrarily deep directory tree, try

```sh
find "$dest_dir" -type f -delete
```

or somewhat more obscurely with `-execdir` and find just the directories and pass in a command like `sh -c 'rm {}/*'`, but in this scenario this is just clumsy and complex.

Comment: Actually that's not what I'm looking for. I made a small change to my question. I'd be grateful I you took another look.

Comment: Changing the question after you receive an answer is generally considered bad form. But thanks for the clarification. Updated the answer with another scenario.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I insist on using `find`, so i had to find a way to exclude the name of $dest_dir from the results. I came up with this: `find $dest_dir -maxdepth 1 | sort | sed '1d' | xargs -ro rm -rf` in which `sed '1d'` does what I wanted.

Comment: @nino "For some reason, I insist on using `find`".  This sound similar in spirit to, "for some reason, I insist on continuing to use a hammer on a screw".  `find` is the wrong tool.  If it is the correct tool for your use case, then this is an XY problem; you are not describing the actual problem you are solving.

Comment: The reason is I later realized I had to use `grep -v` and because of that I couldn't use the `rm -rf "$dest_dir"/*` and I had to use `find` or `ls`.

Comment: That doesn't clarify the use case at all. `grep -v` on what? The file names? You can use [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) to exclude a set of files from a wildcard match.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of `!` in globs. That can replace the `grep -v` part I think. I'll test it now. Thanks a lot.